# PHP Excel reader not reading data after null entries

Tags: php, excel

I would like to get the values from an excell sheet.

Here is my PHP CODE.

```
error_reporting(0);
require_once 'excel_reader2.php';
require_once 'db.php';
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("example.xls");
echo "Total Sheets in this xls file: ".count($data->sheets)."<br /><br />";
for($i=0;$i<count($data->sheets);$i++) // Loop to get all sheets in a file.
{   
    if(count($data->sheets[$i][cells])>0) // checking sheet not empty
    {
        echo "<br>Sheet $i:<br /><br />Total rows in sheet $i is =  ".count($data->sheets[$i][cells])."<br />";
        $count_val  =  count($data->sheets[$i][cells]);
            $data_cnt   =  1;
        for($j=1;$j<=$count_val;$j++) // loop used to get each row of the sheet
        {           
            echo '<br>'.$eid = $data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][1];
            echo ' '.$name = $data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][2];
            echo ' '.$email = $data->sheets[$i][cells][$j][3];
         //BEGIN CODE INSERTED FOR READING DATA AFTER NULL ENTRIES
         if($eid){
            $data_cnt++;
         }else{
            $j =  $j-1;
         }
         if($data_cnt==$count_val){
            break;
         }
         //END CODE INSERTED FOR READING DATA AFTER NULL ENTRIES
        }
    }
}
```

My excell sheet is below

[image]

But the problem is the count of the row returns the row invloves the value

So it returns only 4 .So the loop doesn't read full row.Because the 3,4 records are in 5th and 6 th row of the excell sheet respectively.

In that code I placed another code for reading data after null entries. but it doesn't work.

```
 if($eid){
    $data_cnt++;
 }else{
    $j =  $j-1;
 }
 if($data_cnt==$count_val){
    break;
 }
```

Give me an advise.